# JavaFX - load FXML into FXML without include

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have a window created with FXML in the corresponding controller, I have a button, which loads a small box when a specific button is clicked. The box is designed using FXML as well.

When I load the box and want to add it into the window, I get this error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2362)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2311)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
    at com.clientgui.DataPage.openStaticData(DataPage.java:79)
...
```

And this is my code:

```
private void openStaticData(int dataObjectId, String titel)
{
    try
    {
        URL location = getClass().getResource("StaticDataBox.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(location);
        loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        loader.load();
        final Region page = (Region) loader.load();  //line 79

        StaticDataBox staticDataBox = (StaticDataBox) loader.getController();
        staticDataBox.setDataObjectId(dataObjectId);
        staticDataBox.setTitel(titel);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                getChildren().add(page);
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(DataPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The main window FXML:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.StackPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.clientgui.ClientGUI" prefHeight="675" prefWidth="1200.0" fx:id="root" styleClass="root">
...
</fx:root>
```

The FXML of the box I want to create dynamically:

```
<VBox id="VBox" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.clientgui.StaticDataBox" styleClass="data-box">
...
</VBox>
```

Comment: Can you delete the line 78 and try again.

Comment: That works! Great! But what does loader.load() do to cause that problem?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the instantiated version of `FXMLLoader`, i.e. non-static `load()` method of it. This method obligates that the location is set prior calling it, as explained in its javadoc. So by calling `loader.load()` method, `FXMLLoader` parses the fxml file at a given location, initializes the controller and constructs the node graph. If the `loader.load()` method invoked again, `FXMLLoader` detects that the root has been already set and throws the "Root value already specified." exception.
However invoking the static load() methods of `FXMLLoader` over and over, will not cause this exception. Because the fxml file parsing and other stuff are performed from the scratch over again independently from each call, on each call.